# htaccess 301 redirect dynamic url

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, http-status-code-301

I am moving my site to new domain. Need to redirect pages
from
old-site.com/oldpage.php?id=X
to
new-site.com/newpage-X
(X is number)

Why this rule does not work?

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^oldpage.php?id=(.*)$ http://new-site.com/newpage-$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513308/question-mark-in-the-end-of-rewriterule

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [`RewriteRule`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule) does only operate on the [URL path](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/directive-dict.html#Syntax) and not the URL query. You need to use the `RewriteCond` directive to test the URL query (`%{QUERY_STRING}`). So try this rule:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^(([^&]*&)*)id=([^&]+)&?(.*)?$
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://new.example.com/newpage-%3?%1%4 [L,R=301]
```

This rule will also preserve other parameters in the query.

Comment: thanks, it works. 
but several urls that i tried early with wrong rules still redirect to wrong page. Is it server problem? Why it remember this?

Comment: Its ok it is Firefox remembering this. Strange.

Answer (score 0):

I suspect that you will need to use QUERY_STRING

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^id=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://new-site.com/newpage-%1 [R=301,L]
```

Hope this helps

Comment: if RewriteRule ^oldpage\.php$ http://new-site.com/newpage-%1? , than it is ok
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513308/question-mark-in-the-end-of-rewriterule