# URL Redirecting properly but displaying object not found

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have followed this thread.
[Question mark in the end of RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513308/question-mark-in-the-end-of-rewriterule)

My requirement was also same.
My page is redirecting(301) properly but it's displaying `OBJECT NOT FOUND`

#### My Actual URL

```
http://mydomain.com/iphone_advanced_search_result.php?keywords=test
```

#### My Desired URL

```
http://mydomain.com/search/test
```

#### My HTACCESS Code

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^keywords=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^iphone_advanced_search_result\.php$ search/%1? [R=301,L]`
```

Why am I getting this error? Please Help!

Answer (score 0):

You're matching on a URL that resembles '/iphone_advanced_search_result.php', but your actual URL doesn't contain the '.php', so it doesn't match.

Remove the '.php' check from your rule and it should work fine.

Comment: Sorry. My actual URL which I have edited now in the post above also would have ".php".
Do I need to have a page like this `http://mydomain.com/search/test` in my project?
Actually I want my new URL to behave exactly like the previous URL.

Comment: Yes, the above code does nothing but direct requests from one URL to another. You still need *something* that listens on /search/test

Answer (score 0):

If your desired url to be used by the user is

`http://mydomain.com/search/test`

and your processing script is

```
http://mydomain.com/iphone_advanced_search_result.php?keywords=test
```

Your rewrite should be the other way round like below:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^search/(.+)$ iphone_advanced_search_result.php?keywords=$1 [L]
```

Comment: Ok. It works. But then I guess I will have to manually write the new URL to the browser since it will not redirect me automatically to the new URL.

Comment: Sorry if I misunderstand your question. It depends on what you want to achieve. Would you state your url you want to type in the browser, the url you want to redirect to, and url of the script that process the keywords?