# RewriteRule with question marks htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

i know this been asked a lot
but i still did not succeeded to do it

i have this in my htaccess

```
RewriteRule    ^embed/([0-9A-Za-z]{12})$        /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed&file_code=$1 [L]

RewriteRule    ^embed/([0-9A-Za-z]{12})/(\d+)x(\d+)$        /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]
```

i want it to be

```
RewriteRule    ^embed/?v=([0-9A-Za-z]{12})$     /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed&file_code=$1 [L]

RewriteRule    ^embed/?v=([0-9A-Za-z]{12})/(\d+)x(\d+)$     /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]
```

adding ?v=

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}  ^v=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^embed/%1([0-9A-Za-z]{12})/(\d+)x(\d+)$ /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=$1&w=$2&h=$3 [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^embed/%1([0-9A-Za-z]{12})$      /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed&file_code=$1 [NC,L]
```

not working

example
mysite.com/embed/?v=abcde
mysite.com/embed/?v=abcde/6x6

currently it is 
mysite.com/embed/abcde
mysite.com/embed/abcde/6x6

so now this work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^embed/?$       /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=%1 [L]
```

i have noticed that i have this in the file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} ^(.*)
RewriteRule ^(.*) - [E=HTTP_CGI_AUTHORIZATION:%1]
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING}     ^v=(.*)$    [NC]
RewriteRule ^$       /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=download1&id=%1      [NC,L]
```

i am still trying to make this to work

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.*)/(\d+)x(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^embed/?$       /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=%1&w=$2&h=$3 [L]
```

Comment: You need to use a `RewriteCond` to analyse the query string: `%{QUERY_STRING}`. Have a search for that, there are many questions here that show how do do it.

Comment: yea i know that i have to use RewriteCond but i have no idea how

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513308/question-mark-in-the-end-of-rewriterule?rq=1

Comment: i have already read that but still no clue

Comment: Actually you need to put what you want to happen and an example URL as well because obviously your code is not working so we need to know what you are using your code against.

Comment: @PanamaJack the code without the ?v= is already working... i want to add the ?v= ... this /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed&file_code=$1 [L]
 refer  to this ^embed/([0-9A-Za-z]{12})$ ... i want it to refer to ^embed/?v=([0-9A-Za-z]{12})$

Comment: add code to the question where it's readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not using the rules properly - passing `%1` to the rules won't help you, because you're not matching correctly. `REQUEST_URI` and `QUERY_STRING` are two different things. `RewriteRule` is only able to check the `REQUEST_URI`, and not the `QUERY_STRING`, as shown in the answer suggested by Panama Jack.

To achieve what you want, you need to use the following instead:

```bsh
RewriteEngine On

# Check for mysite.com/embed/?v=abcde/6x6
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&/]+)\/(\d+)x(\d+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^embed/?$       /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=%1&w=%2&h=%3 [L]

# Check for mysite.com/embed/?v=abcde
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([^&]+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^embed/?$       /cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed&file_code=%1 [L]
```

Here, we simply check the query string for each case. If there is a match, only rewrite if we're at `/embed/` (trailing slash optional - you may remove the question mark if you wish for the trailing slash to be required).

Comment: thanks now it redirect to a page but not the correct one

Comment: I changed the second one to `video_embed` (without the `2`). Is that correct now?

Comment: hi thanks to you i have solved 1 problem, can you help me with the other, i have updated the question

Comment: any chance to help me with the second problem ?

Comment: If you make it clear exactly what the problem is, then yes. I see that you're not using the rule I provided in my answer. Or are you?

Comment: If the two rules I provided in my answer work, then please open a new question.

Comment: they did not work i had to change them, then 1 worked, i have edited the question please check

Comment: I have edited my answer. Apologies - I used `$` instead of `%` in the rules. Please try again with the changes.

Comment: to make it work i had to use RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=(.*)$ [NC] instead of RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^v=([a-z0-9]{12})$ [NC] this is working for # Check for mysite.com/embed/?v=abcde but not for # Check for mysite.com/embed/?v=abcde/6x6

Comment: Please try my update. I am signing off now for dinner, so will only see your response tomorrow.

Comment: thanks for the update, its not reading the (\d+)x(\d+), it generate the file code but the weight and height are not generated

Comment: currently it generate this cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=(filecode)/(weight)x(height), it should generate cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=(filecode)/w=(weight)xh=(height)

Comment: That's not what it's doing for me... If I navigate to `/embed/?v=abcde/6x6`, the request is rewritten to `/cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed2&file_code=abcde&w=6&h=6`. If I navigate to `/embed/?v=abcde`, the request is rewritten to `/cgi-bin/index_dl.cgi?op=video_embed&file_code=abcde`. Are there any other rules in your `.htaccess` file? If so, please paste your entire file over at http://pastebin.com and send me the share link.

Comment: Okay, I have [modified your file](http://pastebin.com/BhLvdHHh). It seems that you keep changing things around, and those things do not match your intention. So, I have changed things to match the code you gave me. See the comments for how everything works.

Comment: thank you a lot work perfect, really appreciate your help