# .htaccess redirect mod rewrite

Tags: regex, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have two rules:

```
RewriteRule ^novina\.php\?sid=([0-9]+)&cat=([a-zA-Z]+)$ novina/$2/$1.html [L,R=301,NC]

RewriteRule ^novina/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+).html novina.php?sid=$2&cat=$1 [L,NC]
```

I'm trying first to redirect all old query including urls to better looking folder structured. With the second rule, I'm getting the result for the given url.

Second rule works fine, but the first one doesn't redirec the url. Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RewriteRule does not match Query Strings.

You have to use RewriteCond with %{QUERY_STRING}

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} sid=([0-9]+)&cat=([a-zA-Z]+)
RewriteRule novina\.php novina/%2/%1.html? [L,R=301,NC]
```

Look, you use %n in RewriteRule and not $n

You need to suffix your destination with a question mark.

> The ? at the end of a destination (destinations are not regular expressions) means to go to that destination with no query string.

says [Question mark in the end of RewriteRule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1513308/question-mark-in-the-end-of-rewriterule)

Comment: Thanks, it redirects all right, but now I get /novina/category/118943.html?sid=118943&cat=category. The query string is still present and it creates a loop: ERR_TOO_MANY_REDIRECTS

Comment: I've corrected it - RewriteRule ^novina\.php$ /novina_new/%2/%1.html? [L,R=301,NC] There has to be ? at the end.

Answer (score 1):

You can have your rules as this:

```
Options -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+novina\.php\?sid=([^\s&]+)&cat=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /novina/%2/%1? [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteRule ^novina/([a-zA-Z]+)/([0-9]+).html novina.php?sid=$2&cat=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```